# How to deliver metadata with BreezeJs and ASP.NET WebServices?

Tags: breeze

How can i get data from web service (asmx) using BreezeJs?

My asmx web service returns DTO objects which are not related with datacontext. How can I automaticaly, deliver metadata to breeze, without using Metadata() method from dbcontext?

I have already looked over the Edmunds sample, but in this sample, we have to manually write metadata for each entity. Can I avoid it using asmx web service and DTO objects?

Answer (score 1):

Breeze currently accepts metadata in only two formats, a native json format and a csdl ( also converted to json) format ( used by Entity Framework backed models).  Note that you can also deliver this metadata in combinations of these formats. i.e. via multiple importMetadata calls to the same metadataStore.

For your example you will need to create the metadata for each of your 'DTO' types, but this typically isn't that onerous.  If you have a lot of them you could also write a simple app that uses reflection to build the metadata for you.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a biggish model you don't have to write the metadata by hand. There is an easier way: **use EF as a metadata design tool!**

Take a look at the `FoosMetadataProvider` in the *DocCode.DataAccess.EF* of the **DocCode sample** ([*download it*](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/download)). It generates metadata for a `Foo` class that doesn't actually exist in any database at all! You could model your DTOs as if they mapped to a database with EF.

Using EF as a metadata design tool is a fast way to generate metadata on the server for models that are not actually using Entity Framework for data access. Just pretend that it is ... and then ignore the `MetadataDbContext` thereafter.

You don't have to carry EF in your production code either. You could use it in a separate project strictly for purposes of generating metadata. Pour that metadata into a script (there's an example of that in DocCode as well). Remember ... you're only using EF as a design time modeling tool. No one has to know; I promise I won't tell.

p.s.: EF is pretty good at this modeling business. You're not abusing it and I don't think it's a hack. You're not using the full framework ... and so what. You don't use all of jQuery either; that didn't stop you from serving it to your clients on every page, right?